# Determining inequality through lists

Tags: python, list

Trying to run a loop to determine if list1[0] is less than list2[0] and so on. I want to capture the list index if the condition is true.

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2 = [2, 3, 4, 1, 6]
masterlist = [list1, list2]

for run in masterlist[0]:
    if run < masterlist[1]:
        #value = true
```

Comment: And what happens if the lists aren't equivalent length?  i.e: [1,2,3,4] and [1,2,3,4,5,6]

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> next((el[0] for el in enumerate(zip(list1, list2)) if el[1][0] < el[1][1]), None)
0
>>> [el[0] for el in enumerate(zip(list1, list2)) if el[1][0] < el[1][1]]
[0, 1, 2, 4]
```

Comment: You could make this a bit more readable by doing `for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(list1, list2))`

Comment: Way better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
for index,(value1,value2) in enumerate(zip(list1,list2)):
    if value1 < value2:
        print index
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
4
```